# Merging two wifi hotspots

Tags: wireless-networking

Probably really simple one here, but I have no idea how to word it for a search.

I have two wireless routers in my house and I would like to set them up so that devices will connect to the one with the best signal. Currently they will stay connected to one regardless of how bad the connection is.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/195816/can-i-automatically-connect-to-the-strongest-wifi-network-under-windows-7

Comment: Not quite what im after, my issue is how to set up the network, so that new devices can make their own decisions based on strength, rather than on last connected to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as strait forward as setting them up with the Same SSID. You first need to have a DHCP server that is not part of the router so you don't get duplicate IP's on your network. Second you need to set up the AP's with the same SSID but on different frequencies. This will allow the traffic to not step on each other and your computer should be able to roam between them. Your client decides when it's time to look for a "new" Network but as long as you can roam between then you should be ok. The only problem with this setup is if you start a "session" on one end of the house (on AP-A) then move to the other side and your computer switches to AP-B you will have to re-setup your "session". Prime example is logging into online banking. There are other more elegant ways to do this where your connect to the AP's/Network is seamless but as with almost everything you would need to spend more to get that.

Comment: Currently router A is acting as DHCP server, B is hardwired into A. would that be ok or would I still need a separate DHCP?

Comment: Yes, as long as one device is the DHCP server, this ensures two things, first, as mentioned above already, no duplicate IP's, second is that everyone is on the same IP address schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you have them both set up with the same SSID (And security), your clients should automatically roam between them when received signal hits a certain minimum (usually somewhere around -70dBm).

Unfortunately, it is entirely up to the client when it decides to roam. Some do offer options for setting a more aggressive threshold.