# How can I automatically connect to a wireless network with the strongest signal

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Short background: I work at a manufacturing company and my users aren't the brightest when it comes to computers, when they lose connection to the wireless network they don't know what to do.

We have multiple access points and I need their computers to automatically connect to the one with the strongest signal or try and loop through the networks starting with the one with the strongest signal and try to connect if they're currently not connected to any. All access points have no password, they have different SSIDs.

Any suggestions? is there just a setting for this I don't know about?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/195816/can-i-automatically-connect-to-the-strongest-wifi-network-under-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Windows automatically connect to the strongest signal at the time you turned on your wi fi and it will not change AP until the connection is lost.

Lets say that you have fair signal on SSID1, but on SSID2 you have excelent. If you want to change to SSID2 you can only do it manually by disconnect from one and then connect to other, or toggle wireless ON/OFF and Windows will connect to SSID2, the one with excelent signal at given moment.

This can be done automatically somehow. Sopouse that you have some script or program that will check for wifi signal and if it is not excelent it will toggle ON/OFF wi fi, 
but how do you think to menage that change ? When they are changing network they will have to be disconnected every once in a while, when they are changeing their network.

*Is there any reason why you cant use your router as repeaters on same network?*

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Roaming aggressiveness" in the wifi adapter settings. Try fiddle with those. Also you may need to adjust power management and transmit power... ALso, it's good idea to limit available wireless modes to just one. All this you'll find in Adapters settings.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from:
[Can I automatically connect to the strongest wifi network under Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/195816/can-i-automatically-connect-to-the-strongest-wifi-network-under-windows-7)

You should be able to do this by

```
going to network and sharing center
select change adapter settings
select your wifi adapter and select properties
click the "configure" button on the popup window (network tab)
click the advanced tab
if roaming aggressiveness is there, set it to "highest.
```

Your laptop should now seek out the strongest signal.