# How to automatically connect to the strongest Wifi network on Windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I have two Wifi networks at home ( with different names / SSID's) and I would like to automatically have my Windows 10 device switch to the strongest available wifi as I move through my home.

Is there a way to set this up so I dont have to manually select networks ?

Comment: Hi, the following link might be helpful to you: 
 https://superuser.com/questions/195816/can-i-automatically-connect-to-the-strongest-wifi-network-under-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

I built a Windows app to automatically connect to the strongest wifi.  The service runs in the background and continually scans for available wifi networks, ranks them by signal strength, and connects to the network with the strongest signal.

Installation Instructions -

```
 Download the Windows installation file from github:  https://github.com/aagupta1/ConnectToBestWifiService/blob/master/SetupConnectToBestWifiService.msi.

Doubleclick on the downloaded file - the windows installer automatically installs and starts the service.

The service will run in the background and automatically connect to the wifi with the strongest signal.
```

You can find more info here - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/automatically-connect-to-the-strongest-wifi/fbfd061d-1725-43f0-8673-cc6660b97e63